# ¿Dónde debería insertar el código del modal?

Tags: html, web, modal

Solo he usado el modal un par de veces y nunca estoy seguro de donde insertar su código puesto que como lo entiendo lo realmente importante a la hora de usar el modal es como llamarlo, usando js o algo por el estilo.

En este caso en particular quisiera que al apretar el botón "btn-ver"

```
<table class="tabla-funcionarios">
         <thead class="th-table">
             <tr class="tr-table">
                 <th>Nombre </th>
                 <th>Apellido</th>
                 <th>Email</th>
                 <th class="th-options">Opciones</th>
             </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody class="tb-table">
            <?php 
            $sql = ('SELECT nombre,apellido,email FROM funcionarios');
            $query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){ ?>
             <tr class="tr-table">
                 <td><?php echo $row['nombre']?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $row['apellido']?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $row['email']?></td>
                 <td class="td-options">
                 <a href="#" class="btn-ver"><i class="far fa-eye"></a></i>
                 <a href="#" class="btn-editar"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></a</i>
                </td>
             </tr>
        </tbody>
        <?php
              }
              ?>
     </table>
```

Comment: yo siempre escribo los modales antes del cierre del body, asi me evito cualquier incoveniente a la hora de manipular el dom y tambien tengo el codigo organizado, ya que se que mi codigo principal esta de primero y de ultimo siempre estara mi modal

Comment: Debes de enviar los valores por data al modal por medio de JS data-target="#editModal" data-toggle="modal" data-id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" o usar una función con js enviando parámetros y mostrarlo en el modal

Comment: Mostrar en el modal con JS $('#editModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
      var button = $(event.relatedTarget)   
      $('#id_input').val(button.data('id'));
  })